# Compilacion cruzada de Linux para Windows con libreria allegro5

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, allegro

Estoy intentando usar un compilador cruzado, el mingw64-w64 en la distribución de linux Fedora32. Cuando agrego las librerías externas me dice que el archivo o directorio no se encuentran, intente hacer 2 opciones:

opcion 1:

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  main.cpp -o snake.exe $(pkg-config allegro-5 allegro_font-5 allegro_primitives-5 allegro_audio-5 allegro_acodec-5 --libs --cflags)`

opcion 2:

`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  main.cpp -L/usr/lib/pkgconfig/ -lallegro-5 -lallegro_font-5 -lallegro_primitives-5 -lallegro_audio-5 -lallegro_acodec-5 -o snake.exe`

pero siempre me bota el mismo error:

```
sources/al_conf.hpp:5:10: fatal error: allegro5/allegro5.h: No such file or directory
5 | #include <allegro5/allegro5.h>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

incluso descargue la librería de allegro-5 para windows (nose si eso ayuda en algo) pero tampoco estoy muy seguro de hacerlo funcionar.